# Threat Modeling and Risk Assessment Effort Estimation

Tags: risk-analysis, threat-modeling

is there any way to have a good effort time estimation of a Threat Modeling and Risk Assessment activity for an internal infrastructure (about 30 active nodes)?

In general, is it possible to find a "best practice" to estimate effort time for an activity that detects threats by using Threat Modelling and estimate the risk of threats by following a standard template, such as OWASP Risk Rating score?

Or, according to your experience, is it better to have a "time material" approach for this type of activities?
Thank you in advance

Comment: That's a little like asking "how long is a piece of string?"

Comment: That's my answer when ask me to estimate effort time about a generic infrastructure, and I would like to offer an incremental approach without fixed price ... but I was wondering if there is a way to create a sort of estimation, more "objective" than  the "experience" of security team...

Comment: Your answer, then, is in *scoping*. Scoping the infrastructure and scoping the threats.